# App configuration settings for different releases

Tags: maui

I am developing a .NET MAUI app in VS2022. This MAUI app is targetted for Android PDAs of a different clients of mine. The app is exactly the same, it only changes a couple of variables like API endpoint and language.

I've been searching how to store app configuration files in .NET MAUI like James Montemangno post, but I can't see the way to distribute the application with different appconfig.json files depending on the company that is going to use the application.

In this moment I have two static string variables that I change, compile the application and install on company devices, change variables again with other company's data and compile again.

Is there a better way to avoid compile an apk for each client?

Comment: You can check this document about [how to set different App configuration settings in maui](https://montemagno.com/dotnet-maui-appsettings-json-configuration/).

Comment: already read, but i need to read different App Configuration files. in this article montemango explained how to read an EmbeddedResource file. what i need is have different App Configuration files for each client.